# SignTool error : No certificates were found that met all the given criteria. vs2019

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, wdk

**signTool error : No certificates were found that met all the given criteria. vs2019**

This error some time occurs while building the WDF or WPF Driver Project with "Test Sign" in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 9):

**To solve this issue.**

follow below steps:

**Solution Explorer => Project Properties => Driver signing => General
In "Test Certificate" select "Create Test Certificate"**

after selecting this option new certificate is created to Test Sign the driver.

Comment: Under Project Properties ==> Signing ==> create test certificate

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I just needed to start Visual Studio **as administrator**. That simple! I wish I know, then I won't spent an hour digging into all kinds of project settings.